# Copying these fluffy clouds?

Tags: materials, volumetrics

So, there's plenty of cloud questions and tuts out there, but none seem to give me what I want, or work in 2.8.

The guy I followed, this is what he came out with. The top left is his render, the top right is the model (done with metaballs), and the bottom is his nodes.

[image: The image he shows]

NOTE: the Flakey Bits node is just a Musgrave texture.

The exact thing he said was this: "Spent a while experimenting with a stylised cloud material. Now settled with a simple volume material with displacements, Voronoi for the bulbous shape and Hybrid Multifractal for little whisps, scaled and masked with Noise. Mesh created with metaballs, then converted to mesh." (Also 2.79)

Anyway I've tried recreating this, both in 2.79 and 2.80 with the exact materials, and the results, particularly the displacement, are nothing like this.

From browsing, I've found that lighting is a big part, so I've tried all kinds of suns, hdris, etc, but nothing is working...

Basically, what I'm asking for is someone to try that, and if it works, tell me what I was doing wrong (or how they did it), or if it's not working, try and come up with something that might.

If you need anything else, here's the link to the guy's page. Scroll down a little, and you'll see it.

https://blenderartists.org/t/isometropolis-pd/1132325/35

(Hopefully I've given everything you guys need), tell me if I haven't.

Any and all help is appreciated!

EDIT: pretty sure there's no difference in what happens between 2.79 and 2.80, but someone can feel free to point out that I'm wrong if I am :).

Comment: Wondering if those mapping nodes might have something to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I eventually figured it out.

Not quite sure what I was doing wrong, but I'll say what I did and post the .blend file.

Here's the image I ended up with.

[image]

It's not perfect, mainly the lighting I think, but I'm pretty happy. It matches the 'cartoony' cloud style I was going for.

I started out just making a simple cloud-shape out of metaballs.

I then more or less copied the node setup above, what I actually used being below:

[image]

I then added a subsurf modifier, set to 3, and two displacement modifiers, shown below.

[image]

For both displacements, I used an empty called iCloud to control the coordinates. The first texture was a Voronoi, shown below.

[image]

The second was a Clouds texture, /.

[image]

I then had two suns, one with a strength of 8, and a very slight warm colour. The second was mildly blue, with a strength of 2. They are both pointing down, slighty angled from different sides.

This was my final scene before rendering.

[image]

And that's how I ended up with my render! Might be a bit of a drawn out answer, but I know how long I spent desperately trying to find answers, so I wanted to help out anyone else as much as I could.

EDIT: Here is the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: love the results. Reminds me of the Pixar Short "Partly Cloudy" https://www.pixar.com/partly-cloudy

Comment: Thanks! And I forgot to post the .blend :). Nevermind, here it is.

Answer (score 1):

To make the displacement node shader work, be sure to be on Cycles (won't work with EEVEE) and then enable the displacement in the material.

*Material Tab of the object --> settings --> surface* replace *Bump Only* by *Displacement and Dump*

Then you don't need any modifier on your object and works great.

[image]

We don't see all the set-up of the first shader, then I found the post of the 
[author where he is sharing his file.](https://twitter.com/louisdumont/status/1064863218231853057)